# Python/SQLite: smooth way to set column names in CREATE TABLE

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm building up a table in Python's SQLite module which will consist of 18 columns at least. These columns are named by times (for example "08-00"), all stored in a list called 'time_range'. I want to avoid writing up all 18 table names by hand in the SQL statement, since all this already exists inside the mentioned list and it would make the code quite ugly. Howver, this:

```
marks = '?,'*18
self.c.execute('''CREATE TABLE finishedJobs (%s)''' % marks, tuple(time_range))
```

did not work. As it seems, Python/SQLite does not accept parameters at this place. Is there any smart workaround for my purpose or do I really have to name every single column in a CREATE TABLE statement by hand?

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by "it didn't work"?

Comment: Dynamic column names are a sign that your schema is not well designed. You should be dynamically creating rows, not columns.

Comment: I imagine you could build the `CREATE` string via a list comprehension but then you would have to declare the datatype for each column in the same way (i.e. all STRING or all INT). You wouldn't be able to declare the primary key, or whether certain columns were distinct. In the end, surely it's just easier to print the contents of your list and copy/paste back into code as a starting basis?

Comment: Your `marks` has a trailing comma if you create it like this. Of course you should avoid creating columns dynamically and rethink your design if it requires you to do something like this. Query parameters generally should be used for data, not for identifier names.

Comment: like `col_names = ', '.join([item + ' TEXT' for item in time_range])`. Then `c.execute('''CREATE TABLE finishedJobs ({})''.format(col_names))` but again, I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Thank you. I'd like to clarify that I do not intend to create column names dynamically, I totally agree that this would be bad design. Instead, I'm just looking for a faster way to write them - 18 colums is still quite handable, but imagine large databases with dozens or hundrets of columns...